# mdframed with tikz method: putting line numbers outside of frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-numbering, mdframed

I want to number the lines in a [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) environment with the line numbers appearing on the left of the frame, outside of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=latex]{mdframed}

\newdimen\linenumbersep

\newcommand{\linenumber}[1]{%
  \linenumbersep 4pt%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{innerleftmargin}%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{innerlinewidth}%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{middlelinewidth}%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{outerlinewidth}%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{linewidth}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{{\rmfamily\tiny#1}\hspace*{\linenumbersep}}}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\begin{mdframed}
\linenumber{1}(define fact\\
\linenumber{2}  (lambda (n)\\
\linenumber{3}  (if (= n 0)\\
\linenumber{4}  1\\
\linenumber{5}  (* n (fact (- n 1))))))
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

After typesetting this document, I get

[image]

as expected. But when the `tikz` method is used for drawing the frame by changing the second line of the source document

```
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
```

the line numbers are not visible anymore, giving

[image]

Is it possible to make this example work with the `tikz` method?

I want to use something like this in a package I am writing to typeset a program listing with the help of Pygments. The line numbers would be generated automatically.

Comment: have you seen the minted package?

Comment: @cmhughes yes, but the minted package has some shortcomings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mdframed clips the box at the frame. But I don't know if it intended or a bug.

### Edit 2017:

The problem seems to have been resolved. The patch it no longer needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}


\newdimen\linenumbersep

\newcommand{\linenumber}[1]{%
  \linenumbersep 4pt%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{innerleftmargin}%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{innerlinewidth}%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{middlelinewidth}%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{outerlinewidth}%
  \advance\linenumbersep\mdflength{linewidth}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{{\rmfamily\tiny#1}\hspace*{\linenumbersep}}}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily


\begin{mdframed}
\linenumber{1}(define fact\\
\linenumber{2}  (lambda (n)\\
\linenumber{3}  (if (= n 0)\\
\linenumber{4}  1\\
\linenumber{5}  (* n (fact (- n 1))))))
\end{mdframed}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*\mdf@tikzbox@tfl[1]{%three or four borders
    \path(0,0)rectangle(\mdfboundingboxwidth,\mdfboundingboxheight);% replace \clip by \path
    \begin{scope}[mdfcorners]%
       \clip[preaction=mdfouterline]%
            [postaction=mdfbackground]%
            [postaction=mdfinnerline]#1;%
    \end{scope}%
    \path[mdfmiddleline,mdfcorners]#1;
  }%

\begin{mdframed}
\linenumber{1}(define fact\\
\linenumber{2}  (lambda (n)\\
\linenumber{3}  (if (= n 0)\\
\linenumber{4}  1\\
\linenumber{5}  (* n (fact (- n 1))))))
\end{mdframed}    

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Comment: @percusse: If you mean that you get an error like this `! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option ngerman yet.` ignore it. It will disappear at the next compilation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It isn't a bug. It was the only way to allow three lines.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Does that mean that numbering the lines in this way (so that they appear outside of the frame) and having a three lines frame at the same time is not possible with the tikz method? With the postscript method it works.

Comment: @Romildo: Ulrikes shows you a way ;-) I have to test some other solutions.