# Line numbering with Lineno within Minipage

Tags: minipage, line-numbering

I am trying to add line numbers to a reading passage. The issue is that I can't get them to display when I try to number lines within a minipage environment. Can anyone answer what seems to be a simple problem?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\fmbox}
\newenvironment{fmpage}[1]
{\begin{lrbox}{\fmbox}\begin{minipage}{#1}}
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\fmbox}}} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Introduction:  \\

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center} 
\begin{fmpage}{5in}
\vspace{.25cm} % Maybe look into frame sep
{ %
Satellites \\

\modulolinenumbers[2]
\begin{linenumbers}
When you watch the news and see pictures of weather from around the United States 
or the world, you are seeing data from NOAA's environmental satellites. NOAA's 
environmental satellites provide data from space to monitor the Earth to analyze the 
coastal waters, relay life-saving emergency beacons, and track tropical storms and 
hurricanes. 
\end{linenumbers}

\ldots and then there are some multiple-choice questions about it.
}
\vspace{.25cm}
\end{fmpage} \end{center}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If you add `\linenumbers` after `\usepackage{lineno}`, you'll see that the entire block - `minipage` - is considered as a "line". That's how [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) works.

Comment: Useful Related Question: [Add page and line numbers to a pdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18760/add-page-and-line-numbers-to-a-pdf).

Comment: So what you are saying, @Werner, is that my problem has no solution? Would another framing environment work?

Comment: @Calhistorian: The problem is that using a `minipage` means that the contents has to be gathered/assembled into a block, and the setting of it (at which time line numbers are added) is then void of any idea of having lines; it's now just a block of "something" that fits on a "very tall line." Is the eventual output you're interested in a line-numbered block of framed text of specific width?

Comment: @Werner, yes. It would be nice if I could frame it as well, as I am typesetting a "textbook" with framed boxes of text separated from the main narrative flow. Is there another package that might be more appropriate? Or some kind of manual override within the minipage? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Calhistorian If you really are amenable to different packages, look at the post [mdframed with tikz method: putting line numbers outside of frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44443) or try the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I think I will try both and see which one works best for me. Thank you all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `lineno` provides the possibility to add frame numbers inside boxes by `internallinnumbers`

Here the resulting mwe:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\fmbox}
\newenvironment{fmpage}[1]
{\begin{lrbox}{\fmbox}\begin{minipage}{#1}}
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\fmbox}}} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Introduction:  \\

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center} 
\begin{fmpage}{5in}
\vspace{.25cm} % Maybe look into frame sep
{ %
Satellites \\

\modulolinenumbers[2]
\begin{internallinenumbers}
When you watch the news and see pictures of weather from around the United States 
or the world, you are seeing data from NOAA's environmental satellites. NOAA's 
environmental satellites provide data from space to monitor the Earth to analyze the 
coastal waters, relay life-saving emergency beacons, and track tropical storms and 
hurricanes. 
\end{internallinenumbers}

\ldots and then there are some multiple-choice questions about it.
}
\vspace{.25cm}
\end{fmpage} \end{center}%
\end{document}
```

[image]