# Latex oneline problem

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I need to do same layout as at the picture:

[image]

How can i arrange elements like that? I made a bordered-paragraph with a framebox{\parbox} commands. But i can't place numbers at left from paragraph.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Take a look at the `lineno` package. See for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107063/134144

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273430/11604